# Integration of IBM Watson Chatbot with Discovery Service

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I followed the demo shown [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-with-discovery). Everything works fine in the demo. When I tried to use my discovery collection with my workspace created following the same set of steps that are mentioned in the demo link, then I am getting all the answers from the conversation but not from discovery.

I tested this by uploading various documents and JSON in discovery service but still it is unable to fetch from the discovery service and moreover I am also do not get any exception or error in my logs.

I am using the same sample application folder provided in the above demo URL, I have only changed the Workspace JSON and the environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

If you change just the Workspace, will work just the Conversation 'cause the Workspace_id is from Conversation Service.

For use your Discovery service from IBM Bluemix, you need to set variables inside code or inside the *.env* file.

**Click within your service:**

[image]

**After, will show 3 options, click "Service Credentials"**

[image]

**Replace** the code from conversation-with-discovery (Java) with your credentials and your `EnviromentID`. I attached the link within each option.

You can see your `EnviromentID` when you access your Discovery and click in some collection, in this case, will show within API Information:

[image]

**[Code](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-with-discovery/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/apis/conversation_with_discovery/discovery/DiscoveryQuery.java#L42):**

```
Discovery discovery = new Discovery("2016-12-01");
    discovery.setEndPoint("https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1");
    //username and password from Service Credentials
    discovery.setUsernameAndPassword("{username}", "{password}");
    //enviroment id from your document within your Discovery Service
    String environmentId = "{environment_id}";

    GetCollectionsRequest getRequest = new GetCollectionsRequest.Builder(environmentId).build();
    GetCollectionsResponse getResponse = discovery.getCollections(getRequest).execute();
```

**.env [file](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-with-discovery/blob/master/src/main/resources/server.env#L8):**

In the server.env file, in the "discovery" section.

- Populate the "password" field.
- Populate the "username" field.
- Add the COLLECTION_ID and ENVIRONMENT_ID that you copied from the Discovery UI

Check official documentation for this Discovery Service [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/?java#).

Comment: Obvioulsly, he just set workspace_id. Set  With VCAP services works at IBM Bluemix. For run locally need to set with code or within the .env file. Like IBM developers showed inside read.me